# Convert number into hours and minutes wile reading CSV in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, time

I have CSV file where the second column indicates a time point with the format `HHMMSS`.

```
ID;TIME
A;110500
B;090000
C;130200
```

This situation indicates some questions for me.

1. Does pandas have a data format to represent a time point with hour, minutes and seconds but without the day, month, ...?
2. How can I convert that fields to such a format?

On Python I would iterate over the fields. But I am sure that Pandas have a more efficient way.

If there is no time of day format without date I could add a day-month-year date to that timepoint.

That is an MWE

```
import pandas
import io

csv = io.StringIO('ID;TIME\nA;110500\nB;090000\nC;130200')

df = pandas.read_csv(csv, sep=';')

print(df)
```

Results in

```
  ID    TIME
0  A  110500
1  B   90000
2  C  130200
```

But what I want to see is

```
  ID    TIME
0  A  11:05:00
1  B   9:00:00
2  C  13:02:00
```

Or much better cutting the seconds also

```
  ID    TIME
0  A  11:05
1  B   9:00
2  C  13:02
```

Comment: Answer to 1. Yes, it's `Timedelta`, but it also add `0 days`. Plus, I don't know there is an option for csv to parse the timedelta. you probably need to parse that time manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the parameter `date_parser` in `read_csv` like and the `time` accesor

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csv, sep=';', 
                     parse_dates=[1], # need to know the position of the TIME column
                     date_parser=lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x, format='%H%M%S').time)

print(df)

  ID      TIME
0  A  11:05:00
1  B  09:00:00
2  C  13:02:00
```

But doing it after reading might be as good

```
df = (pandas.read_csv(csv, sep=';')
        .assign(TIME=lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x['TIME'], format='%H%M%S').dt.time) 
        #or lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x['TIME'], format='%H%M%S').dt.strftime('%#H:%M')
     )
```

Comment: What if I need different parser for multiple date/time columns?

Comment: @buhtzsaysgetvaccinated I don't think you can pass an list or dictionary of parsers to `date_parser`, in the doc it does not say you can while it says for other parameters when you can pass several options at once in list or dict

Comment: @buhtzsaysgetvaccinated you can also consider using the parameter converters like `df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', converters={'TIME': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%H%M%S').time()})` and then define for each column you want to parse the parser